# String Requests on AsyncTask

Tags: json, android-asynctask

Hi i would like to ask if someone here knows how to have StringRequests on AsyncTask. I have tried it but i get the error on PostExecute.

> D/MyDebug: Error on JSON Array org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

here is my code.

```
public class MarketsFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String url="http://192.168.1.195/test/test.php";
private static final String STARTING_TEXT ="";
private static String login = null;
private static String debug="MyDebug";

private View rootView;
private ListView lvMarkets;

public static MarketsFragment newInstance(String text)
{
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(STARTING_TEXT,text);
    MarketsFragment marketsHome = new MarketsFragment();
    marketsHome.setArguments(args);
   return marketsHome;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_markets,container,false);

    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    final String c_androidid    =   Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    final Cursor rs = db.getID(c_androidid);
    rs.moveToFirst();
    final String c_login = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.c_login));

    AsyncTaskRunner taskRunner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
    taskRunner.execute(c_login);

    return rootView;
}

private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String requestString="";
    String c_login;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Data...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        c_login=params[0];
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                JSONArray jArray = null;
                try
                {
                    jArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    requestString=response;
                    Log.d("MyDebug",response.toString());
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    Log.d("MyDebug","AsyncTask onResponse Error: "+e.toString());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.d("MyDebug","Volley Error: "+error.toString());
                }
            }){
            @Override
             protected Map<String,String>getParams()
            {
                Map<String,String>params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("c_login",c_login);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return requestString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            MarketsAdapter marketsAdapter = new MarketsAdapter(getActivity(),jsonArray);
            lvMarkets = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvMarkets);
            lvMarkets.setAdapter(marketsAdapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            Log.d("MyDebug","Error on JSON Array "+e.toString());
            progressDialog.setMessage("Error Updating Data. "+e.toString());
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

}

I hope you can help me with this one.

Thanks...

Comment: Is that Solved now?

Comment: not yet..
 
I have already checked on the server side but there is no problem. It generated the JSON Data.. [{"tvSym":"JPY","tvConv":"101.9350","tvDate":"6\/27\/2016 8:25am","tvBid":"102.1050","tvAsk":"102.1200"},{"tvSym":"GBP","tvConv":"0.7466",‌​"tvDate":"6\/27\/2016 8:11am","tvBid":"0.7466","tvAsk":"0.7461"},{"tvSym":"PHP","tvConv":"47.0355","tv‌​Date":"6\/27\/2016 9:37am","tvBid":"47.0295","tvAsk":"47.1300"},{"tvSym":"AED","tvConv":"3.6727","t‌​vDate":"6\/27\/2016 6:57am","tvBid":"3.6725","tvAsk":"3.6742"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***First***

**"End of input at character 0"**.its because of this you got null response which generated that exception.

if the problem is that you're getting a blank response, you should make sure you get a response from the server before trying to parse it (which is "result" in onPost()).

if the problem is a bad JSON, you should try and validate it. http://jsonlint.com/is a very good to check.

***Second***

And if **Error: com.android.volley.TimeoutError** ,
You should set the request's RetryPolicy.

see here..

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
..................
..............

      int socketTimeout = 30000;//30 seconds - change to what you want

       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
       RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
       stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        return requestString;

}
```

**Third**

When you use Volley, there's no need to combine it with AsyncTask. It does the networking stuff on another thread for you.

Thanks..

Comment: I have already checked on the server side but there is no problem. It generated the JSON Data.. [{"tvSym":"JPY","tvConv":"101.9350","tvDate":"6\/27\/2016 8:25am","tvBid":"102.1050","tvAsk":"102.1200"},{"tvSym":"GBP","tvConv":"0.7466","tvDate":"6\/27\/2016 8:11am","tvBid":"0.7466","tvAsk":"0.7461"},{"tvSym":"PHP","tvConv":"47.0355","tvDate":"6\/27\/2016 9:37am","tvBid":"47.0295","tvAsk":"47.1300"},{"tvSym":"AED","tvConv":"3.6727","tvDate":"6\/27\/2016 6:57am","tvBid":"3.6725","tvAsk":"3.6742"}]

Comment: Did you check in onPostExecute(String result) by log? Log.d("result==",">>"+result.toString()); is that getting here?

Comment: @ Kush i have checked and there is no result at all. And as far as i know. it will retrieve all the JSON data on "doInBackground" first then after that it will forward the data on the "postExecute".

Comment: Yae, there is problem. Becaue of empty result jsonArray is not created, check  Log.d("MyDebug",response.toString());  @Raven.. here is that getting?

Comment: i already check the log and there is nothing there and after the error "Error on JSON Array org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of" it comes another error "D/MyDebug: Volley Error: com.android.volley.TimeoutError"

Comment: I already tested it an it returns a response but the only thing is that it should not execute postExecute before it retrieves all the data on doInBackground

Comment: When you use Volley, there's no need to combine it with AsyncTask. It does the networking stuff on another thread for you.